# Pinboard style grid: make first element twice wider with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing a pinboard-style blog (like Pinterest) using the tutorial by [Ben Holland](http://benholland.me/archive/javascript/2012/02/20/how-to-build-a-site-that-works-like-pinterest.html). Each block has an absolute position and its location (top and left) is being calculated with jQuery script http://labs.benholland.me/pinterest/js/script-centered.js

See working demo: http://labs.benholland.me/pinterest/demo-centered.php

All elements in this demo have the same width. It is set in two places: in **CSS** `.block {width: 300px;}` and in **JavaScript** `var colWidth = 300;`

**The Problem:**
I need to make the first *block* to be **as twice as wide as all the others** and make sure that the positioning of the elements is not being collapsed. [Click to see example](http://oi61.tinypic.com/25usmev.jpg).

I know how to complete the **CSS** part:  `.block:first-child {width: 610px;}`
(600px+10px margin)

But due to my limited knowledge of JavaScript, I can't complete the **JavaScript** part. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

---

See JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pq8hqabL/ — works only on window resize

Live demo on the website I'm developing — http://goo.gl/Ckp2Qh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried out using Masonry (http://masonry.desandro.com), and I think I have achieved your desired effect. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pq8hqabL/1.

HTML with masonry loaded:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="masonry js-masonry"  data-masonry-options='{ "columnWidth": 241,"gutter":12}'>
        <div class="item w2">
            Lorem ipsum...
        </div>
        <div class="item w2">
            Lorem ipsum...
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 1024px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.masonry {
  background: #EEE;
}

.masonry .item {
  width:  241px;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.item.w2 { width:  494px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, it makes selectors in javascript a lot easier. You could simply do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var colWidth = 300;
    var bigWidth = 2 * colWidth;
    $('.block:first-child').css({'width': bigWidth + 'px'});
}
```

Of course you could also make bigWidth a string with value '610px', but leaving things as numbers until you actually apply it to css is what I recommend, better for calculations.
Is that what you wanted to know?

PS. If you haven't used jQuery before, all you need to do is link to it *before* any of your other scripts:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

PPS: You could also use the :nth-child() selector:

```
$('.block:nth-child(1)').css({'width': bigWidth + 'px'});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The code above gives me an error: `'Uncaught ReferenceError: setupBlocks is not defined'`.

**setupBlocks** is body onload parameter from the tutorial.

In addition, even if this piece of code would work, I don't think that the position 'top' and 'left' calculations for the rest of the blocks would be correct.

Comment: Do you have the function setupBlocks() defined anywhere in your code? Yes you may have to change your calculations to get all 'top' and 'left' values to be correct. Alternatively, you could set all blocks to be normal width, and then absolutely position a larger one over the first two, by applying a specific class to the first block. Can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes, sure, here's JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pq8hqabL/ — but it works only on window resize (probably because of body onload function). Here is the live working demo on the website I'm developing — http://goo.gl/Ckp2Qh

Comment: Nice site! Ok so I fiddled with your code but I couldn't get it to work, so then I tried out using Masonry (http://masonry.desandro.com/), and I think I have achieved your desired effect. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pq8hqabL/1/. Make sure to check out masonry and all of its options! I think using it will make your project a lot easier. Also, box-sizing: border-box will also make things a lot easier:p

Comment: Thanks a lot, Masonry really worked! Could you post your comment as a separate reply, and I will mark it as accepted?